# Is it possible to somehow disable Web Services API in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

As I know it's not possible technically but maybe I'm wrong and there are some tricks to do that?

Any information appreciated.

Comment: the question is: why?

Comment: for example if you are service provider (dynamics hoster) and want to restrict your legal clients to use system through WEB Service API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because the CRM system internally uses the API so any attempt to disable it would render your installation unusable.

Comment: You are mention "attempt to disable"... does this mean that it is possible in principle? Maybe you know something about the possibility to disable API for a specific user?

Comment: Maybe, and just maybe, the IOrganizationService uses WCF after all, so the same way you make WCF uses certificates with tokens you can make the IOrganitazionServices request this certificates.

Comment: @Sxntk The OrganizationService is very much just a WCF service exposed via the WSHttpBinding.  IOrganizationService is simply the service contract interface and OrganizationServiceProxy is the client implementation of that interface MS provide in the SDK.  No smoke and mirrors.